# Create Batch Payment in Foreign Currency

Tags: currency, xero-api

We are currently using the "Xero API" NPM package and are having an issue when creating a batch payment for a Foreign Currency. We are a British based company and our organisation base currency is "GBP". We have suppliers that are in different countries and their invoice within Xero is setup to use their currency code. For instance, we have a supplier in Australia and their current invoice within Xero is using "AUD".

When we create a batch payment using the SDK Xero created, if we are paying a British invoice we have no issue, however when we pay the foreign one we get the following validation error "Invoice's currency must match the organisation's base currency".

Is it possible when creating a batch payment to a foreign country to use their currency code or does it need to be in "GBP"? We can confirm the foreign supplier account currency code matches the invoice currency code. We also applied a currency exchange rate, but all failed.

```
// Get payment id
const paymentId = (await flowElement.getPropertyStringValue('paymentId')) as string;

// Create the payments for the batch
const payments: Payment[] = [];
const records = (await connection.query(
  `SELECT invoice_id, amount_due FROM finance_bills WHERE payment_id = '${paymentId}'`,
)) as InvoiceAndAmount[];
records.forEach((record) => {
  payments.push({
    bankAccountNumber: account.bankAccountNumber as string,
    invoice: {
      invoiceID: record.invoice_id,
      currencyCode: CurrencyCode.AUD
    },
    amount: record.amount_due,
    currencyRate: 1.93
  });
});

// Get the date for the batch payment
const date = (await flowElement.getPropertyStringValue('date')) as string;

// Build batch payment
const batchPayments: BatchPayments = {
  batchPayments: [
    {
      date,
      account: {
        accountID: account.accountID as string,
      },
      payments,
    },
  ],
};

// Create Xero client (Live)
const xero = new XeroClient({
  clientId: (await flowElement.getPropertyStringValue('clientId')) as string,
  clientSecret: (await flowElement.getPropertyStringValue('clientSecret')) as string,
  scopes: scopes.split(' '),
  grantType: 'client_credentials',
});

// Get token for Xero
await xero.getClientCredentialsToken();

// Make batch payment
await xero.accountingApi.createBatchPayment('', batchPayments);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create foreign currency batch payments in Xero. All bills paid in the batch have to be created as base currency bills.